# MongoDB can't compile on Windows 7

Tags: mongodb, cmake

Trying to cmake mongodb C Driver on Windows 7 and got this error:

```
D:\db\mongodb\mongo-cxx-driver-master\build>cmake ..
-- No build type selected, default is Release
-- Auto-configuring bsoncxx to use boost std library polyfills since C++17 is in
active and compiler is MSVC
CMake Error at src/bsoncxx/CMakeLists.txt:81 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findlibbson-1.0.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "libbson-1.0", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libbson-1.0"
  (requested version 1.10.0) with any of the following names:

    libbson-1.0Config.cmake
    libbson-1.0-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libbson-1.0" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libbson-1.0_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "libbson-1.0" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
```

libbson is installed

Don't understand where should I set a libbson directory

Comment: "Add the installation prefix of "libbson-1.0" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH" - Set environment variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to contain the directory, where `libbson` is installed on your system.

Comment: Tried to set enviroment variable both with libbson/bin/ and libbson drectory with no luck. Seems it is available to set it in some cmakekist file but don't understand exactly where. Libsson doesn't have any .exe files it is just .dll, .lib or include folder with .h files

Comment: Are your `libbson` installation has `libbson-1.0-config.cmake` file? Which **absolute path** to that file?

Comment: I add  BSON_INCLUDE_DIR as Variable in compile options and fixed this issue but got another response to boost instalations. Anyway, seems I solve one problem. Now fighting with boost install